# Adding non-printing characters to barcode using Treepoem and BWIPP (Python)

Tags: python, barcode, datamatrix

I am using barcodes to automate data entry, so I'd like to add non-printing characters to the barcode.  The parse option should be able to do it, but as there's minimal error generation between the Treepoem frontend and BWIPP, it's been challenging to understand what I'm missing.

```
image = treepoem.generate_barcode(barcode_type="datamatrix",
                                  data="hello^TABworld",
                                  options= {"parse": True})
image.convert("1").save("output_barcode.png")
```

I'm getting this barcode [Datamatrix with data: hello^TABworld](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjYEQ.png), instead of this [image: Datamatrix with data: hello world]

Comment: What version of BWIPP is being used by treepoem?  BWIPP introduced the mnemonic control character names in release 2022-07-01.

Comment: I've found a workaround.  Just encode the escape character into the text directly. data="hello/tworld"